# Javascript mousemove function to show element not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to to get a mousemove function to display a custom cursor element i created when the mouse is moved inside the specific div. The custom cursor is an absolute positioned div within the div i want it to appear in. The wierd thing i am seeing is i can see from the developer tools that it is infact working but the custom cursor doesnt actually show. If i however move the custom cursor div outside of the div i want it in and into the main body it displays fine.

I know this must be a simple error on my part but i cant see it! Appreciate any advice.

```js
let customCursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
const section2 = document.querySelector('.section2');
section2.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  customCursor.classList.add('active');
  customCursor.setAttribute("style", "top:" + (e.pageY) + "px; left: " + e.pageX + "px;");

});

section2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  customCursor.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section1 {
  height: 500px;
}

.section2 {
  height: 500px;
}

.custom-cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-cursor.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section class="section1 section">Section 1</section>
  <section class="section2 section">Section 2
    <div class="custom-cursor"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c6m2r17f/

Comment: You can do this using CSS by setting the [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property.

Comment: @dave Newton, fiddle doesn't seem to work I'm afraid, thank you though

Comment: @rufus You cursor is there, it's just shifted down because it's under your 500px section

Comment: @rufus The fiddle works just fine--it's your code, the only thing I changed was the height of the divs so they were actually visible. What I was pointing out is that it works exactly the way you coded it--you just don't want what you actually wrote, and it's not clear what you actually *want*.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Titus comment, you can use CSS with `cursor`.

But if you implemeting it with JS that need to track position of your mouse relative to `section2`, you will need to subtract the `section2` element offset left and top, then subtract half of the cursor width and height to center the cursor:

```js
let customCursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
const section2 = document.querySelector('.section2');
section2.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  customCursor.classList.add('active');
   customCursor.setAttribute("style", "top:" + (e.pageY - section2.offsetTop - (customCursor.offsetWidth/2) ) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX - section2.offsetLeft - (customCursor.offsetHeight/2)) + "px;");

});

section2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  customCursor.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section1 {
  height: 500px;
}

.section2 {
  height: 500px;
}

.custom-cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-cursor.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section class="section1 section">Section 1</section>
  <section class="section2 section">Section 2
    <div class="custom-cursor"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you this looks like its doing the job nicely! thanks for you help

Comment: Glad it help, i forgot to subtract the half of the cursor width and height also, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute
```

is relative to the parent if the parent has

```
position:relative
```

so in order to have the correct position within your section2, you need to use `e.layerY` and `e.layerX` instead of `e.pageY` and `e.pageX` since those are based on the top left corner of your screen. `e.layerY` and `e.layerX` is relative to the container that the mouseevent is attached to.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/42kq1w8m/9/